# Combining integrals with different bounds

Tags: calculus

How do you combine this expression into one single integral?  $$\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{2-x} \,dx \,-\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{nx}-1}{e^x-1}\,dx$$

I thought about substituting x in the first integral for $$x=\frac{u}{u-1}$$ that way the bounds would become the same as the as the second integral but it doesn't work. Why can't you do that? How do you actually combine them?

Comment: Put $x=\frac u {1-u}$

Comment: For the sake of algebraic simplicity you might be better off substituting $u = e^{-x}$ in the second integral or $x = e^{-u}$ in the first integral.

Comment: Note that your second integral will not have a finite value if $n\ge1$.